# The view courses.views.checkout.verifypayment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have this code for verify payment , when user buy some course he will redirect to other page called `mycourse` but when i try to buy course it show error

```
The view courses.views.checkout.verifypayment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

View.py :

```
@csrf_exempt
def verifypayment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        context = {}
        try:
            client.utility.verify_payment_signature(data)
            razorpay_order_id = data['razorpay_order_id']
            razorpay_payment_id = data['razorpay_payment_id']

            payment = Payment.objects.get(order_id = razorpay_order_id)
            payment.payment_id  = razorpay_payment_id
            payment.status =  True
            
            userCourse = UserCourse(user = payment.user , course = payment.course)
            userCourse.save()

            payment.user_course = userCourse
            payment.save()

            return redirect('mycourse')

        except:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Payment Details")
```

Comment: are you getting this error on get request?

Comment: yes when user buy course it must return course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django views must return an [HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects), Your view returns `HttpResponse` only for the POST requests, in case your URL corresponding to this view, got a GET request it will through this error because you are not returning an `HttpResponse` for the get requests.

Solution

```
@csrf_exempt
def verifypayment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST

            return redirect('mycourse')

        except:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Payment Details")

    return HttpResponse("Got a GET Request") #add this line
```

Comment: it tried this but nothing happened , same error

Comment: ops sorry i forget to add return

Comment: make sure the last added line is outside the if block..

Comment: yeah it's work now thank bro ,, just a question i want some help in my app if you can help me i will be thankful

Comment: Yeah sure, post the question

Comment: thanks bro .. here is my question if you can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470969/how-to-use-paypal-instead-of-razorpay-django